# Flutter sleek_circular_slider full circle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using sleek_circular_slider package, but i don't know how to be
the widget as circle, by default it is not

[image]

```
final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
  appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
    customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(progressBarWidth: 10)),
  min: 10,
  max: 28,
  initialValue: 14,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [package documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/sleek_circular_slider/latest/) states that the slider object takes an `appearance` parameter of type `CircularSliderAppearance`. You can then set `angleRange` as a parameter on the appearance to get whatever range you require. By default docs state it is 240 degrees.

To get a complete circle, the code would look something like:

```dart
final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
    appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(angleRange: 360),
        onChange: (double value) {
            print(value);
        });
```

Comment: If the answer is useful kindly mark it as accepted.